# Why is my DataLoader so much slower than a for loop?

Tags: python, pytorch

I am writing a neural-net based classifier for the MNIST dataset. I first tried loading the data manually using loops and indexes for the epochs and batches. In a tutorial I saw someone using the torch.utils.data.DataLoader for this exact task, so i changed my code to use a DataLoader instead. This resulted in major differences in the duration of the learning process.

I've tried to troubleshoot this issue by trying to narrow it down using benchmarks. I always benchmarked on both CPU(i7 8700k) and GPU(1080ti) and the data is stored on my ssd(970 evo).

I first tried to compare Batch Gradient Descent with and without DataLoader and then Mini-Batch Gradient Descent with and without DataLoader. The results were rather confusing to me.

```
|                 | BGD         | BGD with DL | MB-GD       | MB-GD with DL |
|-----------------|-------------|-------------|-------------|---------------|
| Time on CPU     | 00:00:56.70 | 00:05:59.31 | 00:01:31.29 | 00:07:46.56   |
| Accuracy on CPU | 82.47       | 33.44       | 94.84       | 87.67         |
| Time on GPU     | 00:00:15.89 | 00:05:41.79 | 00:00:17.48 | 00:05:37.33   |
| Accuracy on GPU | 82.3        | 30.66       | 94.88       | 87.74         |
| Batch Size      | M           | M           | 500         | 500           |
| Epoch           | 100         | 100         | 100         | 100           |
```

This is the code using DataLoader, stripped down to essentials.

```py
num_epoch = 100
train_loader = DataLoader(batch_size=500, shuffle=False, dataset=dataset_train)

for epoch in range(num_epoch):
    for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        images = images.view(-1, 28 * 28)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(images)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

vs the code using the loop

```py
num_epoch = 100
batch_size = 500
num_batch = int(len(dataset_train) / batch_size)

for epoch in range(num_epoch):
    for batch_idx in range(num_batch):
        images = dataset_train.data[batch_idx*batch_size:(batch_idx+1)*batch_size].view(-1, 28 * 28)
        labels = dataset_train.targets[batch_idx*batch_size:(batch_idx+1)*batch_size]
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = model(images)
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

I would expect the DataLoader to atleast perform somewhere close to the loop in terms of time and performance, but not 10 times slower. I am also confused why the DataLoader affects the model accuracy.

Am I using the DataLoader wrong, or is this just the wrong use case for it and a loop is better suited for what I am doing ?

EDIT: here are two fiddles containing the full code of the [loop](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/1d2fd511-d17d-4d47-a0c9-821e43d3e962/?i=true) and the [dataloader](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/f1b48091-1c81-4337-889b-cff2ac7e2446/?i=true) variant

EDIT: I believe I might have figured out how to fix my main problem, the performance difference between dataloader and loop. By setting the `num_workers` parameter of the loader to 8, i managed to drive down the time for mini-batch with DL on GPU to around 1 minute. While this is definitely better than 5 minutes, it's still bad, considering that minibatch with DL on GPU is on par with the performance of minibatch with loop on CPU.

Comment: you have some transforms in your `dataset_train` object?

Comment: @iacolippo Yes `transforms.ToTensor()`

Answer (score 0):

`transforms.ToTensor()` takes a `PIL Image` or `np.ndarray` in the range`[0, 255]`  as input and converts it to a `torch.FloatTensor` in the range `[0.0, 1.0]` if `np.ndarray` has `dtype=np.uint8` or the `PIL Image` belong to one of the modes `(L, LA, P, I, F, RGB, YCbCr, RGBA, CMYK, 1)` [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torchvision/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.ToTensor)

Rescaling and changing data type affect model accuracy. Also `DataLoader` is doing more operation than your loop over batches, therefore the difference in timings.

P.S. You should shuffle your training data when doing minibatch training

Comment: I still don't understand how else to do it. The dataloader completely eliminates the performance advantage of the gpu.
P.S. shuffling was disabled to get a more accurate comparison to the loop

Comment: Furthermore, the transforms made on the dataset should equally affect the loop and loader variant, shouldn't it? does the loop variant not actually do the transforms although they are made on the dataset and not the loader ?

Comment: You're right about the transforms, then what could affect the accuracy is if one case you shuffle and in the other you don't. About the speed, I don't know, it's hard to answer when I can't run the same code to reproduce your issue.

Comment: You can though, i uploaded the code in my edit. If you have trouble retrieving nn.py, its just a very basic 1 layer neural net with sigmoid activation functions, nothing fancy or out of the ordinary.